# In Xcode 4.5, what is "Compiler Default" for "C++ Standard Library" and "C++ Language Dialect"?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, libstdc++, libc++

What is the value of "Compiler Default" for "C++ Standard Library" and "C++ Language Dialect" in Xcode 4.5?

My guess is libstdc++ and GNU++98, but it would be nice to have clarification.

From the [Xcode 4.5 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW174):

> Projects created using this Xcode release use the new libc++
>   implementation of the standard C++ library. The libc++ library is
>   available only on iOS 5.0 and later and OS X 10.7 and later. 12221787
>
> To enable deployment on earlier releases of iOS and OS X in your
>   project, set the C++ Standard Library build setting to libstdc++ (Gnu
>   C++ standard library).

I notice that creating a new project explicitly sets GNU++11 and libc++, but "Compiler Default" is probably something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the best way to find out:

```
 #include <iostream>

int main()
{
#ifdef _LIBCPP_VERSION
    std::cout << "Using libc++\n";
#else
    std::cout << "Using libstdc++\n";
#endif
#ifdef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
#if __cplusplus == 1
    std::cout << "Language mode = gnu++11\n";
#else
    std::cout << "Language mode = c++11\n";
#endif
#else
#if __cplusplus == 1
    std::cout << "Language mode = gnu++98\n";
#else
    std::cout << "Language mode = c++98\n";
#endif
#endif
}
```

Just build a test project with the compiler defaults and run it.

Comment: Great, thanks for that useful snippet. The answer is as I thought: "libstdc++" and "gnu++98".

Comment: @ribbonwind that's strange; for me the result is libc++ and gnu++11.

Comment: There is some confusion here as to what was asked and answered.  I assumed that ribbonwind was asking what "compiler default" meant when chosen in the build settings.  Others are asking/answering what the default build settings are.  These are two different things.

Comment: I get `libstdc++` and `gnu++98` even though I set the `C++ Standard Library` option to `libc++ (...)` in `Xcode 8`. Does these macros still apply?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei: I just ran a HelloWorld with the Xcode 8 command line tools using `-E -dM` and it output `#define _LIBCPP_VERSION 3700`.  I did not confirm that the IDE does not have a bug with the way it presents options in the GUI.

Comment: @HowardHinnant, can you show me the command in order to run it against my project too?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei:  Create a test.cpp that includes any standard header (e.g. `<type_traits>`).  The compile with `clang++ test.cpp -E -dM`.  I like to pipe that to my editor:   `clang++ test.cpp -E -dM | edit` for easer searching.  The `-E` says "preprocess only".  The `-dM` says list all macro definitions.