# How do I create a project in Xcode that allows me to write in Objective-C++, and have a command-line interface?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I'm working with a group of friends on a project, and we're doing it in Objective-C++, which I understand is just Objective-C with the ability to use C++ as well.

I'm curious how I'd go about creating a project like one of my friends has setup. They have a main.mm that runs everything important and starts the program up seemingly, where I'm using to the `AppDelegate.m` serving that purpose.

How do I get a project where it's just a .mm file that serves as the focal point, but still has all the Foundation properties like `NSDate` and whatnot? I don't want a UI, I just want command line input/output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode, create a new project from the "OS X -> Command Line Tool" template and choose
"Type: Foundation". Then rename "main.m" to "main.mm".

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode File > New Project then select Application under OS X. Choose Command Line Tool and press next. Put in a name and make sure Type is set to Foundation.

Then you'll need to rename main.m to main.mm and link against the c++ std library. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070556/apple-mach-o-linker-id-error-opencv-xcode/15072028#15072028) describes how to add the std lib to the project.

Comment: At least with the current Xcode, libc++ seems to be linked automatically if you have a  main.mm file in your project.