# Build opencv 2.4.10 on Mac 10.10.3 failed

Tags: opencv, osx-yosemite

I tried to build opencv 2.4.10 on Mac 10.10.3 with Xcode 6.3. And the following errors occurred by building.

/Users/Shirui/work/program/opencv-2.4.10/modules/legacy/src/calibfilter.cpp:98:9: error: comparison of array
      'this->latestPoints' not equal to a null pointer is always true [-Werror,-Wtautological-pointer-compare]
    if (latestPoints != NULL)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~
/Users/Shirui/work/program/opencv-2.4.10/modules/legacy/src/calibfilter.cpp:526:9: error: address of array
      'this->latestCounts' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Werror,-Wpointer-bool-conversion]
    if( latestCounts )
    ~~  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.

The commands I used:

```
mkdir path-to-opencv-source/build
cd path-to-opencv-source/build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make -j8
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's actually a problem that happens when building OpencV with **clang**.

It was first [discussed here](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4048), and [fixed here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/35f96d6da76099d80180439c857a4abe5cb17966).

You can do the fix youself, of course, or just download a more recent version of OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am used to install opencv 3.0 but because of this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650527/opencv-c-qt-cornersubpix-error/29724281#29724281 I can not use it when compiling my project. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm told that you can disable the warning globally by adding -Wno-tautological-pointer-compare to your compiler flags, or on a one-off basis by wrapping the variable you're testing in parentheses.