# Can't use imshow in xcode 5 on OSX 10.8

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, imshow

I'm kind of puzzled as I cannot use `imshow` from the opencv library. I use plenty of other function from opencv, but I get this error, when I want to show my matrix/image.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::namedWindow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::imshow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The the codelines/functions throwing this error are:

```
cvStartWindowThread();
namedWindow("DisplayImage", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Display Image", img_bgr);
```

where `img_bgr` is my desired matrix.

I'm working on OSX 10.8.5 with Xcode 5.1.1 and opencv-2.4.10 was installed via [this walkthrough](http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/).

Anyone has an idea and can help why I can't call those above functions? I searched for threads concerning this problem, but none seemed to be satisfying.

EDIT:

Have uninstalled and installed OpenCV twice now. Once with Cmake itself (as application) and once with help of [this tutorial](https://drthitirat.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/install-opencv-2-4-5-to-my-macbook-air-os-x-10-8-3-mountain-lion/). Nothing worked out still get the same error.
Does no one have an idea?

Comment: Are you passing proper flags to linker (path, name of the `opencv` library?

Comment: I just followed this [walkthrough](http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/11/howto-setup-xcode-6-1-to-work-with-opencv-libraries/). Unsuccessful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trials/hours of troubleshooting I finally got it running. It was sort of steamroller tactics, but whatever. I just formatted my laptop and installed 10.10 Yosemite on a fresh partition.
After some [building issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724408/build-opencv-2-4-10-on-mac-10-10-3-failed) with OpenCV, which are initially [explained here](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4048) and [solved here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/35f96d6da76099d80180439c857a4abe5cb17966) it now runs perfectly.