# fatal error: 'QTKit/QTKit.h' file not found when I build OpenCV on mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I have followed this http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/ to install OpenCV on my mac.
When I do this step :
    $ make -j4
a problem happened:

```
fatal error: 
      'QTKit/QTKit.h' file not found
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>
        ^ 1 error generated. make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_qtkit.mm.o]
Error 1 make[1]: ***
[modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2 make: ***
[all] Error 2
```

Comment: I suggest you use Anaconda, have a look at [this tutorial](https://rivercitylabs.org/up-and-running-with-opencv3-and-python-3-anaconda-edition/)

Comment: You are not alone with QTKit and Xcode8 problem: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/4303

Answer (score 4):

Try building it like this instead:

```
cmake -DWITH_QUICKTIME=OFF -DWITH_GSTREAMER=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. ; make -j4
```

Comment: Worked for me to resolve the QTKit error - lead me to this error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724408/build-opencv-2-4-10-on-mac-10-10-3-failed

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround solution to fix the issue:

1. Download **MACOSX SDK** [here](https://codeload.github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/zip/MacOSX10.11.sdk).
2. extract head files from `MacOSX10.11.sdk/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Headers/`
3. Create a folder under opencv source file folder: `opencv-3.2.0/modules/highgui/src/QTKit`, and copy all header files into the folder.
4. Follow the regular opencv build steps. When you run make -j8, you don't need set `"-DWITH_QUICKTIME=OFF -DWITH_GSTREAMER=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF"`

This works for opencv2.x and 3.x

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to install opencv on mac using brew?

```
brew reinstall opencv3 --HEAD --with-python3 --with-ffmpeg --with-tbb --with-contrib
```

Worked for me on MAC OS SIERRA.

Answer (score 0):

This error is  because of QuickTime Kit was deprecated in OS X v10.9,and Apple suggest to use AVFoundation framework instead [Apple API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/qtkit#overview).

OpenCV (version 3.1.0) is relaying on QuickTime Kit.
So, when you trying to install OpenCV (before version 3.1.0) on OSX Sierra, It will raise error when you make.

**Try install the master version of opencv will be OK !**

OpenCV had AVFoundation Framework supported in https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/7159

Answer (score 0):

use `--with-quicktime` or `-DWITH_QUICKTIME=TRUE`. It will use QUITCKTIME Instead of QTKit for Video I/O

Comment: QuickTime is depracated too in Sierra `fatal error: 'QuickTime/QuickTime.h' file not found
#include <QuickTime/QuickTime.h>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @feiyun
Here is a workaround solution to fix my issue:

1. Download **MACOSX SDK** [here](https://codeload.github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/zip/MacOSX10.11.sdk).
2. Extract head files from `MacOSX10.11.sdk/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Headers/`
3. Copy all `Headers` and `Modules` files into your corresponding folder.

```sh
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
cd QTKit.framework
cd Versions
cd Current
sudo cp -r /Users/mac/Desktop/MacOSX-SDKs-MacOSX10.11.sdk/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Versions/Current/Headers .
sudo cp -r /Users/mac/Desktop/MacOSX-SDKs-MacOSX10.11.sdk/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Versions/Current/Modules .
cd ..
cd ..
sudo ln -s Versions/Current/Headers Headers
sudo ln -s Versions/Current/Modules Modules
```

```
(tf20) mac@Macbook:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   24 Jan  4 10:09 Headers -> Versions/Current/Headers
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   24 Jan  4 10:10 Modules -> Versions/Current/Modules
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   26 Dec 17 16:33 QTKit.tbd -> Versions/Current/QTKit.tbd
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  128 Dec 17 16:33 Versions
```

4. Follow the regular opencv build steps. When you run `make -j8`, you don't need set `"-DWITH_QUICKTIME=OFF -DWITH_GSTREAMER=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF"`

This works for opencv2.x and 3.x