# OpenCV Installation failure due to QTKit

Tags: python, macos, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to install openCV for Python on my Mac but after going through a bunch of tutorials, none seem to work for me. These are the steps I took

1. Installed `CMake`
2. Downloaded the OpenCV library
3. Used `CMake` to generate the Unix Makefiles
4. Run `make` on the generated files

And this is where the error arises.

> fatal error: 'QTKit/QTKit.h' file not found

I searched and I found ***QTKitDefines.h*** instead at
*/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/*

Upon opening, it read

> QTKit has been deprecated in 10.9.
>   AVFoundation and AVKit are the frameworks recommended for all new development 
>     involving time-based audiovisual media on OS X.  In order to transition your 
>     project from QTKit to AVFoundation please refer to:
>     "Technical Note TN2300 Transitioning QTKit code to AV Foundation".

I tried searching and nothing has deem fruitful. All similar issues I found, the users still had `QTKit.h`. Take for instance this [folk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590741/fatal-error-qtkit-qtkit-h-file-not-found-when-i-build-opencv-on-mac)

Any help will sincerely be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround by downloading the QTKit framework from [this](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases) repo then I simply merged my framework with the one included in the repo and continued with my installation process successfully.

**EDIT for Merging files**

By dragging and dropping the downloaded framework into the same location as my current QTKit framework; since they both have the same name, a popup prompted me with three choices of either *replacing*, *merging* or *cancel* then I simply went for merging because this allows me to still keep my updated framework along with the repo one.

Comment: can you clarify how you merged frameworks? I am looking at only using QTKit but doing it via creating soft link from /Libraries/Framework to extracted SDKs.

Comment: I downloaded latest code via git rather than tar and it fixed the issue.