# Python package OpenCV installation issue on mac Sierra

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, macos-sierra, qtkit

I am facing issues while installing OpenCV package on Mac Sierra (10.12.1)

I followed all the steps mentioned in the link :

```
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/
```

I got issues related to `QTKit.h` file not being present. This is a known issue and so I followed several solutions but none worked.
I then followed all possible solutions present here :

```
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6913
```

&

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590741/fatal-error-qtkit-qtkit-h-file-not-found-when-i-build-opencv-on-mac
```

But none of them seem to work (or so I guess)
I cannot see the location where OpenCV has been installed.

I did try to check in the TERMINAL by doing an import and it works without issues.

```
IMPORT CV2
```

But when I run my code on the python IDE (PyCharm), I get the error for CV2 module not found.

I also tried searching in Pycharm's IDE if I could see a CV2, but i couldn't.

Please help!

Comment: Also, to verify the CV2 version.. i did a `cv2.__version__` in the python terminal and it gave `2.4` instead of the expected `3.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issues installing OpenCV with Python 2.7 following Adrian's tutorial on pyimage. I got around the issue with compiling on macOS Sierra by switching to the **‘pr7266’ branch** for **opencv** and switching to the **‘master’ branch** for **opencv_contrib**

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
$ cd opencv
$ git fetch https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git +pull/7266/head:pr7266
$ git checkout pr7266 # instead of 3.0.0 or 3.1.0
```

See instructions at - **https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/7266**

I've never used PyCharm before so can't help there, hope this helps though!

Comment: Thanks. 
This did help - I am now able to install CV2 successfully

BUT - opencv doesnt seem to reflect in my python for soem reason.

I tried the following :

`$ python import cv2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'import': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: that's strange! In any case - I found my install was being unstable and ended up installing OpenCV2 in a virtual envelope using Anaconda - the following tutorial worked great:

Comment: https://rivercitylabs.org/up-and-running-with-opencv3-and-python-3-anaconda-edition/                                                                                                    (I know it's not a solution for actually compiling OpenCV but it saved me a lot of hassle! hopefully will try & compile from source when time allows) also - I meant you can install OpenCV3 with Python2/3 using the tutorial :)