# how to solve the error: 'QTKit/QTKit.h' file not found when I build OpenCV on MacOS10.12

Tags: python, macos, opencv

Environment:MacOS 10.12, CMake 3.9.0, python 2.7

I try to compile Opencv on mac using this [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/),and after I followed Step 8, I got the error as follows:

```html
/Users/niceycb/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_qtkit.mm:46:9: fatal error: 
      'QTKit/QTKit.h' file not found
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_qtkit.mm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 35%] Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_shape.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../../lib/libopencv_shape.a(precomp.cpp.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: ../../lib/libopencv_shape.a(precomp.cpp.o) has no symbols
[ 35%] Built target opencv_shape
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And I tried to solve ''QTKit/QTKit.h' file not found', I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590741/fatal-error-qtkit-qtkit-h-file-not-found-when-i-build-opencv-on-mac).

One solution is:

```html
brew reinstall opencv3 --HEAD --with-python2 --with-ffmpeg --with-tbb --with-contrib
```

The error is

```html
Error: opencv3: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-science/opencv3.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting end-of-input
?SDγ?qm?????5??...)?
            ^
```

Another solution is that using $brew  edit  opencv3 and commenting the following  4 lines:

```html
if build.with?("python3") && build.with?("python")
  # Opencv3 Does not support building both Python 2 and 3 versions
  odie "opencv3: Does not support building both Python 2 and 3 wrappers"
end
```

Then I use  $ brew install opencv3 --with-contrib. But the same error occurred.

```
Error: opencv3: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-science/opencv3.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting end-of-input
?SDγ?qm?????5??...)?
            ^
```

Comment: Why not just compile the source from `OpenCV` and use `cmake`?

Comment: @ l'L'l  I'm quite new about that, I think the tutorial I followed does compile the source from OpenCV and use cmake. Tutorial link:http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/

Comment: The tutorial seems like it's way more steps than it needs to be; it's quite simple to just download the source from the official site and compile it. What is the intended usage for OpenCV, are you planning on using it with Xcode, building an app, etc?

Comment: @ l'L'l  Actually,I'm following this project guide to test model.(https://github.com/imatge-upc/activitynet-2016-cvprw/blob/master/misc/step_by_step_guide.md) What should I do first is to build an environment. This model require to have a Python virtual environment,and the page asserts that the opencv installation  install the Python package. The tutorial I followed to build opencv meets my requirements.

Comment: Well, it appears you were using the wrong tutorial. I think you want this one instead: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/28/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-2-7/

Comment: Yeah，I'm too careless！Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.