# Unable to add opencv2-2 framework to iOS project

Tags: objective-c, opencv

I'm trying to add the opencv2-2 (the latest release) framework to my iOS project, but I am encountering this error when I build.

> ld: framework not found opencv2-2
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The opencv2-2 framework appears in the Link Binary with Libraries section of the Build Phases tab. If it's relevant, this is my import statement in ViewController.m:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2-2/core.hpp>
#endif
```

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have it in link library path?

Comment: @JohnTracid Are you asking if I have it in the link binary with libraries section? I do have it there.

Comment: I mean Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths.

Comment: @JohnTracid I have $(PROJECT_DIR) set to recursive. Is that sufficient?

Comment: @JohnTracid Is the issue caused by the fact that the latest version of the framework is named opencv2-2.framework and not opencv2.framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your framework file should be named `opencv2.framework` and your import statement should be `#import <opencv2/core.hpp>`.

I'm not sure where you got the incorrect name `opencv2-2`. Maybe you downloaded `opencv2.framework` twice and Mac automatically renamed the second copy to `opencv2-2.framework`.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of the framework from the OpenCV website. It was named opencv2-2.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest version (3.2.0) from the OpenCV website now.  The file inside the ZIP is named opencv2.framework. Maybe you unzipped it twice and got a second copy named opencv2-2.framework, but that's not the correct name.

Comment: I guess that must've been it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I changed the framework name from opencv2-2.framework in opencv2.framework and it works

Comment: Please refrain posting such things as an answer. Once you get enough reputation you would be able to do comments.

Comment: @neer17 this seems to be an answer to my question.