# dlib error in porting Linux program in mac OS

Tags: linux, macos, dlib

Below errors happens in mac OS X 10.10, while trying to compile linux-made code in mac...
I located dlib as below, and it seems the compiler finds the dlib properly.

set (DLIB_INCLUDE_DIR "/usr/local/Cellar/dlib/19.15/include")
set (DLIB_LIB_DIR "/usr/local/Cellar/dlib/19.15/lib")

Is there any compatibility issue even using same dlib?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::set_stream(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      dlib::get_serialized_frontal_faces[abi:cxx11]()  in libPoseExprLib.a(DlibWrapper.cpp.o)
  "H5::H5Location::openDataSet(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
      readH5Dataset(H5::H5File const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) in libPoseExprLib.a(BaselFace.cpp.o)
  "H5::Exception::getDetailMsg[abi:cxx11]() const", referenced from:
      BaselFace::load(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) [clone .cold.29] in libPoseExprLib.a(BaselFace.cpp.o)
  "dlib::base64::decode(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&) const", referenced from:
      dlib::get_serialized_frontal_faces[abi:cxx11]()  in libPoseExprLib.a(DlibWrapper.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::__basic_string_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::str() const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      dlib::fatal_error::check_for_previous_fatal_errors()      in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::fatal_error::dlib_fatal_error_terminate()      in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      dlib::fatal_error::check_for_previous_fatal_errors()      in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::fatal_error::dlib_fatal_error_terminate()      in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::str(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::push_back(char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      dlib::error::error(dlib::error_type, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::error::error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::str(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::put(char)", referenced from:
      dlib::fatal_error::check_for_previous_fatal_errors()      in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::fatal_error::dlib_fatal_error_terminate()      in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush()", referenced from:
      dlib::fatal_error::check_for_previous_fatal_errors()      in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::fatal_error::dlib_fatal_error_terminate()      in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      dlib::base64::encode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream() in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::base64::decode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream() in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream() in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream() in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
      dlib::base64::encode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::base64::decode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sync()", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::imbue(std::__1::locale const&)", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::uflow()", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::setbuf(char*, long)", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::xsgetn(char*, long)", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long)", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::showmanyc()", referenced from:
      vtable for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_streambuf()", referenced from:
      dlib::base64::encode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::base64::decode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_streambuf()", referenced from:
      dlib::base64::encode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream() in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::base64::decode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream() in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream() in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream() in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringbuf() in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      ...
  "std::__1::iostream_category()", referenced from:
      dlib::base64::encode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::base64::decode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::cerr", referenced from:
      dlib::fatal_error::check_for_previous_fatal_errors()      in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::fatal_error::dlib_fatal_error_terminate()      in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      dlib::fatal_error::check_for_previous_fatal_errors()      in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::fatal_error::dlib_fatal_error_terminate()      in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      dlib::fatal_error::check_for_previous_fatal_errors()      in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::fatal_error::dlib_fatal_error_terminate()      in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::init(void*)", referenced from:
      dlib::base64::encode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::base64::decode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::failure::failure(char const*, std::__1::error_code const&)", referenced from:
      dlib::base64::encode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::base64::decode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::ios_base::failure::~failure()", referenced from:
      dlib::base64::encode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::base64::decode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ios()", referenced from:
      dlib::base64::encode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream() in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::base64::decode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream() in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream() in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream() in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "typeinfo for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      typeinfo for std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "typeinfo for std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from:
      typeinfo for std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "typeinfo for std::__1::ios_base::failure", referenced from:
      dlib::base64::encode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
      dlib::base64::decode(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >-in-std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > in libdlib.a(base64_kernel_1.cpp.o)
  "_dgesdd_", referenced from:
      int dlib::lapack::gesdd<double, 0l, 2l, 2l, 0l, 0l, 1l, 2l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >(char, dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 2l, 1l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 2l, 2l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&) in libPoseExprLib.a(DlibWrapper.cpp.o)
  "_dgesvd_", referenced from:
      int dlib::lapack::gesvd<double, 0l, 3l, 0l, 3l, 3l, 1l, 3l, 3l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >(char, char, dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 3l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 3l, 1l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 3l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 3l, 3l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&) in libPoseExprLib.a(DlibWrapper.cpp.o)
      int dlib::lapack::gesvd<double, 3l, 0l, 3l, 0l, 0l, 1l, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >(char, char, dlib::matrix<double, 3l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 1l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 3l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&) in libPoseExprLib.a(DlibWrapper.cpp.o)
      int dlib::lapack::gesvd<double, 0l, 0l, 0l, 0l, 0l, 0l, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >(char, char, dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&) in libPoseExprLib.a(DlibWrapper.cpp.o)
      int dlib::lapack::gesvd<double, 0l, 2l, 2l, 0l, 0l, 1l, 2l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >(char, char, dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 2l, 1l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 2l, 2l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&, dlib::matrix<double, 0l, 0l, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char>, dlib::row_major_layout>&) in libPoseExprLib.a(DlibWrapper.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Not only do you need to tell the compiler where the header/include (`XXX.h`) files are, but also you need to tell the linker where the library (`XXX.dylib`) files are.

Comment: What compiler, and what standard library? You should probably show a compile command. Also see [Apple Mach-O linker and multiple “undefined symbols” error using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15070556/608639) and [Error when compiling some simple c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7533321/608639)

Comment: I am no expert, but there is a `dlib.cmake` with the **homebrew** `dlib` package, so I guess you can use something like `find_package(dlib PATHS /usr/local/Cellar/dlib/19.15/lib/cmake/dlib)`