# Which C/C++ compiler does Xcode use?

Tags: c++, c, standard-library

I just started to get my hands dirty with C/C++, and I am still getting my head around the different concepts (I've written mostly Java previously). I'd really like to know which C/C++ compiler is used and also which standard library is included. Also, I'd like to know where I can find the API documentation of the respective standard library (like the Java SE API docs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not an XCode user, but it seems to be Apple's LLVM Compiler (by default) according to Apple's website: https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/. But, I guess, like any other IDE XCode does support other compilers like GCC. Also depends on your XCode version it seems: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/03/21/compiler-options-in-xcode-gcc-or-llvm.html

Here's a question in SO that asks about the default compiler and the answer seems to have the code to find just that: [In Xcode 4.5, what is "Compiler Default" for "C++ Standard Library" and "C++ Language Dialect"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865226/in-xcode-4-5-what-is-compiler-default-for-c-standard-library-and-c-lan)

According to this post 4.6 uses clang instead of GCC for C++: http://cplusplusmusings.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/c-and-xcode-4-6/

P.S.: Googling does help ;)

Comment: "Googling does help", funny enough this question is now the second highest search result on Google for "what compiler does XCode use".

Comment: Top result for me on DuckDuckGo...  The student has become the master.

Answer (score 7):

For C++:

Xcode 4.6.2 uses the Clang C++ compiler frontend with LLVM as backend which is conform to the C++11 standart and uses libc++ as the standart library.

[Here](http://devimages.apple.com/llvm/videos/LibC++.mov) you can finde a apple presentation about libc++.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed the second half of the question was never really answered:

> ... I'd like to know where I can find the API documentation of the
>   respective standard library ...

A simple Google search will reveal a wealth of information about this.  *Do note*, however, that the "C++ Standard Library" is **not** the same thing as the "C Standard Library," so be careful of that when searching and reading.  C++ has its roots in C, but the two have diverged to become separate languages that share a lot of commonality -- and a lot of hidden differences.

The canonical reference work regarding this is titled, appropriately enough, "The C++ Standard Library" by Nicolai M. Josuttis, published by Addison-Wesley.  Many C++ programmers keep this on their bookshelves as a reference.

There is a good online reference for the library at https://cppreference.com/.

If you are interested in specifics of the LLVM implementation used by Apple's Xcode, see https://libcxx.llvm.org/ .

For a comprehensive list of the most highly recommended books and references for C++, Stack Overflow already has a very good FAQ regarding this: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).